# Can i set 443 as default web port which means it can only be accessed via https and no port 80

Tags: http, https, httpd, httpd.conf, network-protocols

As title says,

I want to set my apache to listen on 443, and will configure SSL.

So, My Question  is :-

1). Does that mean, i will not have port 80 or any other port which is no ssl ?
2). My site can only be accessed via https and no http ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice against doing this using an iptables redirect. The reason is that when someone browses your site using HTTP, their browser is not expecting an SSL session handshake. It *may* work, but it's definitely not guaranteed to.

Instead, I'd have a separate Apache instance (or a VirtualHost) that listens on port 80. That apache instance/VH should be configured to *only* issue a redirect to the SSL-enabled site, like this:

```
RedirectMatch /(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
```

That way the browser will understand that it's being sent off to an SSL site, and there will be no problem with the SSL negotiation.

Comment: yup.. i tried with iptable and this was not working... thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you configure apache with no listening configuration on port 80 and ensure that you configure it to listen on port 443 with ssl correctly then yes, your server will not listen on any non-ssl ports.

Comment: so, can i redirect all user browsing http with the help of iptable :-
`root@linux# iptables -t NAT -a PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --to-port 443 -j REDIRECT`

Comment: It wouldn't work. In your web browser you will see something like - "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect the HTTP requests to HTTPS without initializing the SSL connetion. So, iptables will not help you. You need to do that with your web server.